# Using i18next with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, internationalization, i18next

Is it possible to use i18next with razor? If not, any other ideas about how to translate labels using razor?
The only option I think is to keep the html tags instead of razor.

**Example:**

```
@Html.LabelFor( model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3", @data-18n = "test.name" } )
```

It gives me an error on `@data-i18n` saying it does not exists in the current context.

Comment: Are you just wanting to add the attribute `data-18n="someValue"` to the label element?

Comment: Then its `new { data_18n = "someValue" }` i.e. underscore character - razor translates that to a hyphen when the html is generated

Comment: Oh man, I would never realize that. Thank you a lot! @StephenMuecke